# Permission to edit a node by multiple users

Tags: 7, nodes

Suppose there is one node (Like `node/4`) which the Admin can edit. My requirement is to give permission to multiple users to edit the same node i.e. `node/4`. Please help how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

The [Nodeaccess](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module might also help:

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set default access controls per content type, and also define which roles are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is the module that i really looking for. Again thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to install a node access module that allow the admin to:

1. Create access control lists (ACLs) to individual nodes; and
2. Add and remove individual users from an ACL.

The module named [Flexi Access](https://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess) lets you do exactly that.

> The Flexi Access module will provide a simple and flexible interface to the ACL (Access Control List) module. It will let you set up and mange ACLs naming individual users that are allowed access to a particular node.
>
> The module let you manage access to individual nodes. The administrator may grant individual users the right to: View (read), update (edit/write), and delete the node.

It depends on the [ACL](https://drupal.org/project/acl) module.  (It actually provides an administrative interface to ACL.)

Disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of Flexi Access.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will try this and let you know if encounters any problem.