# How to change permissions to a role when a content is set as published

Tags: users

I have been working with Drupal 8 and need help: I have a News content type, and an Editor role type. This Editor role can view/edit/delete his own content. I want that Editor roles can't edit/delete their own content when this content is published by Admin roles.

I have been searched and I found Permissions by fields, Permissions by terms, Groups and Custom Publish options modules, but I can't make this works.

Maybe this can be done with php, but I don't know how.

Please, any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grant edit access for specific nodes to 1 or more selected users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260443/how-to-grant-edit-access-for-specific-nodes-to-1-or-more-selected-users)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity;

function mymodule_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
  $type = $node->getType();
  // Is it published?
  $nodeIsPublished = $node->isPublished();
  if ($type == 'news' && $operation != 'view' && $nodeIsPublished == 1) {
    if($account->hasRole('rolename')) {
       return  AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
    else {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Also, the [Override Node Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module allows permissions to be set for each field within the *Authoring information* and *Publishing options* fieldsets on the node form.